# Rails: Login session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this 5.2 rails app that I have just upgraded to 6.1 version.

I could not login after upgrading.  It looks like the session parameter is not set correctly.

```rb
  def staff_callback
    email = params[:email]
    unique_code = params[:unique_code]

    staff = Staff.find_by(email: email)
    raise 'password does not match' if staff.authenticate(unique_code) == false

    session[:login] = { type: :staff, staff_id: staff.id }

    puts "staff callback 47923"
    puts session[:login]
    puts "staff callback end 8043"

    redirect_to staff_forms_path
  end
```

The session code was assigned in `staff_callback` but in the `require_staff_login` it is nil.

```rb
  def require_staff_login
    login = session[:login]

    puts "require staff login"
    puts session[:login]

    if login.nil?
      logger.debug 'user is not logged in'
      redirect_to auth_staff_path
      return
    end

    ...
  end
```

The error log is here:

```
> Started GET "/staff/forms" for ::1 at 2022-02-19 15:03:43 +0800
> Processing by Staff::FormsController#index as HTML require staff login
> 
> user is not logged in Redirected to http://localhost:3000/auth/staff
> Filter chain halted as :require_staff_login rendered or redirected
> Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 424)
```

The authcontroller:
https://gist.github.com/somaria/543c7da1a6f4f544d17a10eea1d93301

The applicationcontroller:
https://gist.github.com/somaria/016733a02b7781deb1d720cf1e288a70

The Gemfile:
https://gist.github.com/somaria/5a9e4b7873bcccfde30461a201b1cf36

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the error log for further clarity.

Comment: I would suggest to try the following to figure out the issue. 1. Try checking the response on the client to see if it has a set cookie header for session_id.  2. Set session[:login] to a simple 1 or 0 value.

Comment: Is it a Rails API app?

Comment: no, it is using webpacker with react-rails